# Heroku Deployment and traffic

Tags: node.js, heroku

Since only one free dyno is available. How many users can simultaneously run my application? 
And how does it calculate how many free dyno hours have been used

Comment: This is a question for more for heroku support and also depends significantly on your app - language, concurrency, complexity, database. How would we know how your app is constructed? We also don't know off by heart what hardware it's hosted on or how many people are sharing your resources etc. You will have to do stress tests on your app.

Answer (score 1):

As Dominic mentions in the comments, this will depend heavily on how your application is architected -- what web server it's using, how quick responses can be returned, etc.

From the "Free dyno hours" perspective, the clock is ticking whenever the dyno is up and running. After 30 minutes of no activity, the dyno will idle and the clock will stop ticking. You can read more about this here: [Free Dyno Hours](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours)